# Check an inequality if one condition holds

Tags: functions, inequalities

```
A = Abs[-1 + 1/(1 + β)] + Abs[-((1 + 2 α + Sqrt[1 + 4 α + 4 α β])/(2 α + 2 α β))]
```

Is `A <1` if `Abs[β]<Abs[1+4 α]` ?

How can I check the above statement in Mathematica? Does the `TrueQ` and `If` functions work?

Comment: What is assumed about $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: Clearly, it is not true for `{α -> 10, β -> 1}` or many other instances.

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are complex numbers.

Comment: The `Reduce` command says what for real parameters the statement is false:

    Reduce[{A < 1, Abs[\[Beta]] < Abs[1 + 4 \[Alpha]]}, {\[Alpha], \[Beta]}, Reals]

Answer (score 1):

maybe this give you some idea:

```
A[α_, β_] := 
  Abs[-1 + 1/(1 + β)] + 
   Abs[-((1 + 2 α + 
         Sqrt[1 + 4 α + 4 α β])/(2 α + 
         2 α β))];
f[a_, b_] := If[(Abs[b] < Abs[1 + 4 a]) && (A[a, b] < 1), {a, b}];
Tally@Flatten@
  Table[f[RandomInteger[{1, 10000}], 
    RandomInteger[{1, 10000}]], {1000}]
```

I know this is not an answer but I am under 50 reputation and con not to post a comment